# Vim: how to automatically highlight each line containing a keyword?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, vim, vim-plugin, vim-syntax-highlighting

if is a ".log" file, want to make every line containing keyword "dog" in the file to be in red, and make every line containing keyword "cat" in the file to be in yellow. This should be done automatically when I open a ".log" file in vim. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far, or what code have you seen that does something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, define the colors as *highlight groups*:

```
:hi Dogs ctermbg=red guibg=red
:hi Cats ctermbg=yellow guibg=yellow
```

You can add (window-local) highlighting via the `:match` commands or the `matchadd()` function. By matching the entire line containing the keyword, you'll get all highlighted. The `:autocmd` installs that for your log files (though I would prefer to use Vim's *filetype* detection instead of hard-coding the file pattern).

```
:autocmd BufWinEnter *.log call matchadd('Dogs', '^.*dog.*$') | call matchadd('Cats', '^.*cat.*$')
```

The benefit of `:match` is that is doesn't interfere with syntax highlighting (which would be an alternative). The downside is that the highlighting will persist when you view a non-log buffer in the same window. (You can fix this by adding more autocmds, but it's not trivial.)

Comment: @romainl: I often think the same when I return to the browser and see that you've already answered a bunch. I think the Vim community here is pretty well served. Thanks (also to Kent, ZyX, glts, etc.)!

Comment: @romainl You are fast too!. when I open the page, oh, there is already an answer, Ingo is fast! when I'm about to post a "you are fast", I saw your comment!